# Convert SplFileInfo Object To Array Problems

Tags: php

I have searched SO and went through all of them.  Many don't seem to apply to my problem but supplied information that I tried to apply.  Result was many parse errors.  I can't seem to apply them correctly.  This is my first use of iterators.  So, after a few days trying I need help.

The original code was taken form the PHP manual.  I turned it into a function and added the code to remove dot and dot dot entries (. and ..).  I then added code to return an array of files so I can use it in a foreach statement.  Problem is that I don't have access to the properties.

```
<?php
function getDirectoryListing($path)
{
 $dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
 $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
 $files = array();
 foreach($iterator as $file)
 {
  if(strpos($file, ".", -1) !== false)
  {
   continue;
  } // Closing brace for if(strpos($file, ".", -1) !== false)
  $files[] = $file;
 } // Closing brace for foreach($iterator as $file)
 return $files;
}

$files = getDirectoryListing("I:\cef-inc.net/images/database/");
print_r($files);
?>
```

When I print_r $files I get:

Array
(
[0] => SplFileInfo Object
(
[pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => I:\cef-inc.net/images/database\calendar.ico
[fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => calendar.ico
)
)

When I echo $file in the foreach I get the pathName but not the fileName.

What do I need to do in the function to put everything in an array?

Thank you for looking,

Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an array of [SplFileInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/class.splfileinfo.php) objects. You should use their [getFilename()](https://www.php.net/manual/splfileinfo.getfilename.php) method to access their filename without the path.
When you echo the object, you’re calling [__tostring()](https://www.php.net/manual/splfileinfo.tostring.php) method.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm sure I tried a variant of your suggestion but failed.  I was able to convert everything to an array by changing `$files[] = $file;` to `$files[] = array("path" => $file->getPathName(), "name" => $file->getFileName());`